# delimiting data in a mysql database without exporting it

Tags: mysql, database, csv

Is it possible to Delimit data in a mysql database row? 
I have data which exceeds about 2million entries, so exporting to csv, and doing it manually is not working as database is refusing to dump data.

the data is in format

```
url.com?some=0
url2.com?some=14
```

Is it possible to remove the ? and the data that follows after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first things first. It doesn't matter how big your database is, MySQL *should* dump to CSV without issue. I've successfully dumped tables containing twice the number of records you're dealing with. Of course, part of that assumes that RAM and disk space are a non-issue which may not be the case.

In regard to your question about filtering data, yes it is possible. I'm going to assume your column is named "url" for my example below, so remember to change that if it is named something else.

In essence, you would run a query like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, "?", 1);
```

That will change all values of URL to only contain text before the first occurrence of a question mark.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes the database is on a shared server, so they limit the query runtime, which is probably why it stops at around 100k.
I just ran it, and it worked out perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to chop up those strings. For example:

```
mysql> select url, case when locate('?', url) = 0 then url else substring(url, 1, locate('?', url) - 1) end as truncated from urls;
+------------------+-----------+
| url              | truncated |
+------------------+-----------+
| url.com?some=0   | url.com   |
| url2.com?some=14 | url2.com  |
| url3.com         | url3.com  |
+------------------+-----------+
```

so this should do the trick:

```
update your_table
set url = case when locate('?', url) = 0 then url else substring(url, 1, locate('?', url) - 1) end
```

Another option is [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
mysql> select url, substring_index(url, '?', 1) from urls;
+------------------+------------------------------+
| url              | substring_index(url, '?', 1) |
+------------------+------------------------------+
| url3.com         | url3.com                     |
| url.com?some=0   | url.com                      |
| url2.com?some=14 | url2.com                     |
+------------------+------------------------------+
```

so this should also work:

```
update your_table
set url = substring_index(url, '?', 1)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, yes it did. :) I was not aware of the SUBSTRING_INDEX query. Thanks for also editing my post, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jasmeet: You're welcome, Matt got his `substring_index` approach in while I was adding some links and my `substring_index` version so you should accept his answer rather than mine.